# How do you list all items from all databases located in a specific tablespace in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, tablespaces

I'm trying to clean out some old tablespaces in my postgres instance, and I can't seem to figure out how to list *everything* in a specific tablespace.

`SELECT * from pg_tables WHERE tablespace ='cold_storage'` returns items from the *current database* in the tablespace, but short of iterating over every database and querying within that database for the tablespace contents, I haven't figured out how to do this.

`pg_tables` seems to be db-specific, whereas (I think) tablespaces are global for a postgres instance.

Answer (score 1):

> `pg_tables` seems to be db-specific, whereas (I think) tablespaces are global for a postgres instance.

That's true. But there is no way of knowing what's inside of a tablespace without connecting to the specific databases and checking their catalogs. Iterating is the only option. Think of it like a glorified virtual storage system.

You may consider running `pg_dumpall --schema-only` and trying to parse that output if you're interested.

Comment: If *tablespaces* were also db-specific, that'd make sense, *but they're not*.

Comment: @FakeName consider this, making and removing a tablespace requires you to be a database superuser. That means you can connect to every database *anyway*. I'm not saying what you want is impossible  to do, only that no one has done it. noting keeps a Leger of what is in a tablespace in remote databases.

Comment: That is extremely annoying. There *is* a global Leger of the *size* of all the table spaces (see `pg_catalog.pg_tablespace_size(oid)`). As it is, it just makes maintenance a pain.